# use module signature definition in module implementation

Tags: coq

I'm not very familiar with modules in Coq, but it was brought up in a recent question I asked. I have the following code.

```
Module Type Sig.
Parameter n : nat.
Definition n_plus_1 := n + 1.
End Sig.

Module ModuleInstance <: Sig.
Definition n := 3.
End ModuleInstance.
```

Coq complains about the definition of `n_plus_1` when I try to run `End ModuleInstance`. I'm not sure if this is a correct way to use modules, but I want it to just use the definition in the signature, it's a complete definition that doesn't need any additional information. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: It complains "rightly", in the sense that `ModuleInstance` should provide all the fields defined in the signature. A different topic thou is what the interpretation of `Definition` in the signature should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to put your definitions into a separate "module functor" (basically a module-level function: these are modules that takes other modules as parameters) so that `Sig` contains only parameters:

```
Module Type Sig.
  Parameter n : nat.
End Sig.

(* this is the module functor *)
Module SigUtils (S:Sig).
  Definition n_plus_1 := S.n + 1.
End SigUtils.

Module ModuleInstance <: Sig.
  Definition n := 3.
End ModuleInstance.

Module ModuleInstanceUtils := SigUtils ModuleInstance.
```

It's not terribly hard but there is one big limitations: you can't use any of your utilities as part of the signature (eg, to make type signatures shorter). Another limitation is that your basic definitions and derived definitions/properties are in separate modules, so if you qualify your references you'll have to use the right name. This is irrelevant if you import the modules, though.

This is the pattern the standard library follows in a few places; for example, the `FSetFacts` and `FSetProperties` functors.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to https://stackoverflow.com/a/49322214/53974, one can sometimes use `Include`, which supports a very limited special case of recursive linking.
Like in that answer, you should put your definitions in a module functor, but then you can `Include` that, both in the rest of your signature, and in the implementing module. That allows to reuse your definitions to shorten the declarations, and to have them as part of the same module.

```
Require Import Omega.

Module Type Sig.
  Parameter n : nat.
End Sig.

(* this is the module functor *)
Module SigUtils (S:Sig).
  Definition n_plus_1 := S.n + 1.
End SigUtils.

Module ModuleInstance <: Sig.
  Definition n := 3.
  Include SigUtils.
End ModuleInstance.
Print ModuleInstance.

Module Type Sig2 <: Sig.
  Include Sig.
  Include SigUtils.
  Parameter n_plus_1_eq: n_plus_1 = 1 + n.
End Sig2.

Module ModuleInstance2 <: Sig2.
  Include ModuleInstance.

  Lemma n_plus_1_eq: n_plus_1 = 1 + n.
  Proof. unfold n_plus_1. omega. Qed.

  Lemma n_plus_1_neq: n_plus_1 <> 2 + n.
  Proof. unfold n_plus_1. omega. Qed.
End ModuleInstance2.

Print ModuleInstance2.
```

However, you'll want to beware the semantics of `Include` (see e.g.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49717951/53974). In particular, should you include a module in two different modules, you'll get distinct definitions. Above, `SigUtils` is included once in a `Module Type` and once in an implementing `Module`, which is allowed.

EDIT: I found a big application of this pattern in the Coq standard library. 
Lots of properties of numbers are proved generically and collected in various module types (such as `NExtraProp` [here](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/6d6b2d7132bc768783bad6738d778519c28c8f08/theories/Numbers/Natural/Abstract/NProperties.v#L27-L30)), and then used in concrete definitions through `Include`, such as [here](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/6d6b2d7132bc768783bad6738d778519c28c8f08/theories/Arith/PeanoNat.v#L727).